# Is there something like "metrics" and "monitor" modules for Kovan?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, rinkeby, kovan

I would like to monitor some parameters for Kovan and Rinkeby clients. Geth provides a monitor module that works with Rinkeby specifying --metrics when launching the client, and attaching to the client by `geth monitor --attach=http:127.0.0.1:8545 parameter`. I'm unable to do the same with Kovan, which is launched using parity. This https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/572 makes me think something similar could be implemented.

Any help would be appreciated.